# Keras Activation Functions Tanh Vs Sigmoid

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an LSTM that utilizes binary data, ie the labels are all 0's or 1's.

This would lead me to use a sigmoid activation function, but when I do it significantly underperforms the same model with a tanh activation function with the same data.

Why would a tanh activation function produce a better accuracy even though the data is not in the (-1,1) range needed for a tanh activation function?

**Sigmoid Activation Function Accuracy:**
Training-Accuracy: 60.32 %
Validation-Accuracy: 72.98 %

**Tanh Activation Function Accuracy:**
Training-Accuracy: 83.41 %
Validation-Accuracy: 82.82 %

All the rest of the code is the exact same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence is usually faster if the average of each input variable over the training set is close to zero. And tanh has a zero mean. It’s likely your data is normalized and has a mean near zero?

Ref: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/activation-functions-why-tanh-outperforms-logistic-sigmoid-3f26469ac0d1

Comment: My data is stock price data that I have transformed into stock price returns. Yeah that makes sense, as my data is centered around 0. I haven't intentionally normalized my data tbh, the reason I changed the data from stock prices to stock price returns was to eliminate the difference in scales between prices. So I guess, I unintentionally normalized it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the interval of (0, 1] if gradient is diminishing over time t, Then sigmoid gives better result. If gradient is increasing then tanh activation function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, how would I know if the gradient is increasing/decreasing over time? What would I need to plot?

Comment: Plot the loss function, if it’s stable-y decreasing over time (like an L kind of shape, things should be ok. If there’s very jagged and unpredictable spikes, then there could be an issue with the gradients being backpropped. Also check the weights in the network and make sure they’re not NaN or abnormally large immediately after beginning training

Comment: `code`                                                                              https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff                                                                         
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu')
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Forward pass
  y = layer(x)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

# Calculate gradients with respect to every trainable variable
grad = tape.gradient(loss, layer.trainable_variables)